# Eclipse ide color given set of words

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse with ABAP development tools and would like to add a highlight or simple underline to a selected set of words.
For example, if there is a word REFACTOR in a comment, I'd like it to be Bold with an underline.
I've tried to add a keyword in ABAP Developement>Editors>Source Code Editor>ABAP Keyword, but it didn't work.
How can I achieve it?